# Java Bean Validation API’s @Valid not working (Spring in action)

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

I am following the book "Spring in Action, 5th Edition". Currently on Chapter 2 where validation is being applied to the forms. I have followed the exact same steps in the book but, but my forms don't recognize that there are any errors.

OrderFromController.java

- Using Java Bean Validation API’s @Valid on the Order object being passed into the processOrder method

```
package com.example.tacocloud.contoller;

import com.example.tacocloud.dto.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/orders")
public class OrderController {

    @GetMapping("/current")
    public String orderForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("order", new Order());
        return "orderForm";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String processOrder(@Valid Order order, Errors errors) {
        if(errors.hasErrors()){
            log.info("Handling errors");
            return "orderForm";
        }

        log.info("Order submitted: " + order);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

OrderObject.java

- Object on which validation should be performed

```
package com.example.tacocloud.dto;

import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.CreditCardNumber;

import javax.validation.constraints.Digits;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

@Data
public class Order {

    @NotBlank(message = "Name is required!")
    private String name;

    @NotBlank(message="Street is required")
    private String street;

    @NotBlank(message="City is required")
    private String city;

    @NotBlank(message="State is required")
    private String state;

    @NotBlank(message="Zip code is required")
    private String zip;

    @CreditCardNumber(message = "Not a valid credit card number")
    private String ccNumber;

    @Pattern(regexp="^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])([\\/])([1-9][0-9])$",
            message="Must be formatted MM/YY")
    private String ccExpiration;

    @Digits(integer=3, fraction=0, message="Invalid CVV")
    private String ccCVV;
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>taco-cloud</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>taco-cloud</name>
    <description>Example from Spring in Action 5th Edition</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: This exact question has already been answered before. Use Hibernate Validator 6 not 7.

Comment: Remove  <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>